# Replace duplicate character after first pattern

Tags: sed

With this data

```
aaa:
  - bbbb: ccc ddd' {eeee  [fff
    kkk: mmm   nnn"   oo   pp
```

I like to have removed all duplicate spaces after the first `:`

```
aaa:
  - bbbb: ccc ddd' {eeee [fff
    kkk: mmm nnn" oo pp
```

Using `\b` doesn't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl` (assuming there's only one `:` per line):

```bash
$ perl -pe 's/ +(?!.*:)/ /g' ip.txt
aaa:
  - bbbb: ccc ddd' {eeee [fff
    kkk: mmm nnn" oo pp
```

If you can have multiple `:` but you still want to squeeze multiple spaces after the first `:`, you can use this:

```bash
perl -pe 's/^[^:]+(*SKIP)(*F)| +/ /g'
```

---

With `sed`:

```bash
$ sed -E ':a s/^([^:]+:.*) {2,}/\1 /; ta' ip.txt
aaa:
  - bbbb: ccc ddd' {eeee [fff
    kkk: mmm nnn" oo pp
```

`:a` is a label for the substitute command. As long as a match is found, `ta` will jump to the label, thus replacing all possible matches.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/(^[^:]*:( \S+)*)  +/\1 /;ta' file
```

Match on two or more spaces following a `:` and replace by a single space, then repeat until no more matches.

Alternative:

```
sed -E ':a;s/(^[^:]*:[^ ]*) +/\1\n/;ta;y/\n/ /' file
```

Replace all space or spaces after a `:` with a newline and repeat until no more matches. Then translate all newlines to spaces (newlines are never present in the pattern space unless the user places them there).